# Why doesn't type inference (var) work with the ASP.NET GridView.Rows property?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

In this code fragment

```
foreach (var row in grid.Rows) { }
```

the type of row is inferred as Object instead of GridViewRow. I have to explicitly declare the type to work with a GridViewRow:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows) { }
```

GridView.Rows returns a GridViewRowCollection and GetEnumerator on the collection "Returns an enumerator that contains all GridViewRow objects in the GridViewRowCollection." If I access a single row from the collection by index

```
var row = grid.Rows[0];
```

the type is correctly inferred. Why can't the compiler infer the type for row in the foreach declaration?

Edited to add: Interesting responses, I didn't think to look for the obvious problem. ListView.Items implements `IList<ListViewDataItem>`, so this looks like an oversight to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `GridViewRowCollection` implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` and `ICollection` interfaces, which are not strongly-typed like this, but its `Item` property is strongly typed and returns a `GridViewRow`. Nice one Microsoft!

Comment: Maybe if they didnt rush all these version they would have had time to actually implement all these missing interfaces :|

Answer (score 3):

`Rows` does not implement `IEnumerable<GridViewRow>`.